# How to create a rewrite rule with one reference and two parameters to three parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess file (located where ad.php resides), I would like to rewrite the following urls:

```
http://example.com/ad/some-AlpHAnumEriC123-reference.html
http://example.com/ad/some-AlpHAnumEriC123-reference.html?i=123
http://example.com/ad/some-AlpHAnumEriC123-reference.html?i=123&s=456
```

to:

```
http://example.com/ad.php?r=some-AlpHAnumEriC123-reference
http://example.com/ad.php?r=some-AlpHAnumEriC123-reference&i=123
http://example.com/ad.php?r=some-AlpHAnumEriC123-reference&i=123&s=456
```

God is this hard! I have currently in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^ad/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html/?$ ad.php?r=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

...but that doesn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I am not good in rewrite rules but try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/ad/(.*)\.html?(.*)$ ad.php?r=$1&$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but no that's not running. print_r($_GET); only reveals Array( [i] => 123 ) for my url with all three values